# C# SQL Command : WHERE today's date and a custom time

Tags: c#, sql

The datatype of appointment will be datetime

Let's say I want to list out the appointments of using today's date and in between the time of 11.00AM to 7.00PM

How should i write the query inside my c# program?

```
SELECT Appointment FROM table WHERE Appointment between 11AM and 7PM.
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have date column in your table? if so, what does it look like, what is the type?

Comment: the appointment datetime format in my table is *7/1/2015 12:16:14 AM*

Comment: What part of this task do you have a problem with? Do you know how to create a connection to a database? Do you know how to create a command? Do you know how to create/add parameters to the command? Do you know how to execute a command? Do you know how to use a datareader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var startDateTime = DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0);
var endDateTime = DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(19, 0, 0);
```

Pass those values as parameters into your query.

Comment: I don't think OP asking this. `How should i write the *query* inside my c# program?`

Comment: The OP already has the correct SQL query text, so the only remaining thing to ask is how to construct the values. Hence my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This  works also in SQL-Server 2005 and below:

```
SELECT Appointment FROM table 
WHERE Appointment between 
     DATEADD(hour, 11, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
AND  DATEADD(hour, 19, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d695/252/0)

Answer (score 0):

Since you asking the query, you can use a little bit [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx), [`GETDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) and [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) conbinations like;

```
SELECT Appointment
FROM table
WHERE Appointment between
DATEADD(HOUR, 11, (GETDATE() - CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),GETDATE(),114)))
and DATEADD(HOUR, 19, (GETDATE() - CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),GETDATE(),114)))
```

And `table` is *really* a bad name for a table. Choose a specific name instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Appointment FROM table WHERE datepart(hour,Appointment) between 11 and 18
```

will give times between 11:00:00.000 and 18:59:59.999